# How can I incorporate multiple conditions in highlighting cells of a column in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet with multiple columns of data in excel and I want to highlight in red the cells of one particular column named "FCCR" if the number is < 1.0 and the contents of another column (meant to explain why something is <1.0) are empty.

I am thinking I locate the FCCR Column using some logic like:

```
Dim fccrHeader as Range

Set fccrHeader = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("FCCR", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Where I am stuck is in thinking about how to highlight the cell IF and only IF the FCCR value is less than 1.0 AND the comment column is empty. Do I have the right idea for looking up the FCCR column header? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: You could do this with conditional formatting alone, why do you wish to use VBA?

Comment: I am not able to do it with CF either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and tested the following and it does as you ask:

```
Sub foo()
Dim val As Variant
Dim ColumnNumber As Long
Set val = Sheet1.Rows(1).Find("FCCR", lookat:=xlWhole)
ColumnNumber = val.Column
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Sheet1.Cells(i, 12).Value = "" Then 'Change the number 12 to reflect the column which might be empty
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, ColumnNumber).Value < 1 Then
            Sheet1.Cells(i, ColumnNumber).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 '3 is equals to red
        End If
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting for this, using a formula?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? I put it into an Active-X control button but you could do it on worksheet_change if you wanted. Its a bit long winded compared to what you will probably find from other users

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim fccrHeader As Range
Dim col, otherCol, row As Integer

Set fccrHeader = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("FCCR", lookat:=xlWhole)
col = fccrHeader.Column
otherCol = 7  ' comment column

For row = 2 To 10 'end of data constant or use search
   If Cells(row, col).Value < 1 And Cells(row, otherCol).Value = "" Then
       'also highlights if both are empty, add that logic to check for ""

       With Cells(row, col).Interior
           .Pattern = xlSolid
           .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           .Color = 255
           .TintAndShade = 0
           .PatternTintAndShade = 0
       End With
    End If
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: I would clear all highlights in that row at the beginning of this subroutine ^^

Comment: Hey, How would you alter the Find part to Find the Column header given that instead of "FCCR" it was "Fixed-Cash Coverage Ratio "%""

Comment: Is there a way to target just part of that header? something like Find(Left 5 characters ..."Fixed") Or something like that?

Comment: Set ratioHeader = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("Fixed-Cash Coverage Ratio", lookat:=xlPart)